# How to "peel off" segments of a sphere?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I want to make a plant that has long 'slitlike' leaves (long, and narrows to a point at each end). So I made a UV sphere and have removed the horizontal edges so i just have the slits 'on the sphere' as it were. Now I want to "peel off" each slit individually and shape it so that it has the shape of the leaf. How might I do that?
thanks

the plant should look like this: [enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSnake_plant.jpg)

Comment: You can use proportional editing to get the twisted effect.

Answer (score 3):

Although there are other better ways to do this, but for your question:

I think you are asking how to separate part of a object as a new one. Basically, in Edit mode, select the part you want to peel off, hit <kbd>P</kbd> and choose **Selection** to separte the selected part as a new object.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to make it into separate objects, you can press <kbd>Y</kbd> and you will separate vertices. It will still be part of the same object.

Yet another option is to duplicate a segment with <kbd>shift + D</kbd>. This is the same as <kbd>Y</kbd> but the original geometry remains.